# Testing CLI app with mocha.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I want to test a CLI app and want to receive user input while the test is running, since mocha.js has 200ms limit the test is failing. So I want to know how to halt the test while the script is getting input and resume after getting it.

Comment: What kind of tests do you write? As a general rule, automated tests should never ever depend on user input and just run by themselves, so you can run them often. Not saying that you should not write async tests, but please consider hard coding the input your user has to type in into the test code.

Comment: I am a creating an option parser which will prompt for user input in case there is a validation error and I want to simulate that. As Bulkan has pointed out I will see stream-expect and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase test timeouts like so;

```
describe('increased timeout', function(){
  it('should not timeout', function(done){
    this.timeout(2000);
    setTimout(done, 1500);
  });
});
```

But I don't recommend you do this. You can use [nexpect](https://github.com/nodejitsu/nexpect) or [stream-expect](https://github.com/rsolomo/node-stream-expect) to simulate user input. This way you can write alot of automated tests.

Example usage of [stream-expect](https://github.com/deoxxa/toy-robot/blob/master/test/ui.js#L2)

Answer (score 0):

Your test runner can have the timeout param added to it, something similar to this.

`mocha -r ts-node/register test/index.ts **--timeout 15000** --reporter mochawesome`

Answer (score -1):

You should make your test async. Add `done` argument and invoke it when you done.
http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/ - check **Asynchronous code** section for samples.

http://jsfiddle.net/iskomorokh/3jnoyovb/9/

Timeouts can be disabled this way:

```
this.enableTimeouts(false);
```

And here is a [link](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#enableTimeouts) to docs

Comment: Making a test async won't help as Mocha will still timeout if the user does not respond fast enough for the test to call `done()` before the timeout delay.

Comment: @Louis check this, please: `it('Prompt', function (done) {
            var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
            if (person) {done()};
        });` If you wait event 10 secs test won't fail with time out if you supplied the name.

Comment: If you have a **complete and tested** example of what you are suggesting, then please put it into your answer.

Comment: Provided link in my original answer.

Comment: The crucial part of that fiddle is the call ``this.enableTimeouts(false);``, which you do not mention at all in your explanation. Your explanation makes it look like the **only** thing needed is to make the test asynchronous, but it is not the case at all.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry about that. The problem is that I had checked my first sample in prepared environment, so I have forgotten to mention that crucial part. Glad that we have finally closed the case.